# How unique is ManagedThreadID?

Tags: .net, multithreading

For ManagedThreadID, MSDN says:

> Gets a unique identifier for the current managed thread.

In what context does "unique" apply?

Is this unique per process?
Per [application domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Domain)?
Per machine?
Per .NET runtime? (if I have both MS.NET and [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29) running)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thread ID is unique per process during a thread's lifecycle. After the thread terminates, its number can be reused.

Comment: See http://rocksolid.gibraltarsoftware.com/development/logging/managed-thread-ids-unique-ids-that-arent-unique for proof

Answer (score 2):

Since threads from the `ThreadPool` also have to honour this property, and there is one `ThreadPool` per process (as stated in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx)), I would think that the ManagedThreadId is most likely unique per process.